# Firefox Addon Request Module - Authentication

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using firefox addons sdk.

I have created a plugin and I wanted to send request out of it. I came across following code on Mozilla developer site.

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var latestTweetRequest = Request({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mozhacks&count=1",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    var tweet = response.json[0];
    console.log("User: " + tweet.user.screen_name);
    console.log("Tweet: " + tweet.text);
  }
});

// Be a good consumer and check for rate limiting before doing more.
Request({
  url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    if (response.json.remaining_hits) {
      latestTweetRequest.get();
    } else {
      console.log("You have been rate limited!");
    }
  }
}).get();
```

Here I cannot get any option to pass credentials along with request. As long as it is possible I want to avoid passing credentials along with url e.g. http://username:password@example.com, because many time special characters in password creates issue. So how to pass credentials with this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var { encode, decode } = require("sdk/base64");

// use encode() to base64 encode your credentials
var encodedCredentials = encode(email + ':' + password);

var testRequest = FRequest({
    url: url,   
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedCredentials
    },      
    onComplete: function(response){                     
        addOnPanel.port.emit('event', response.json)
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: What if the password contains '@' character?

Comment: It can contain any character. That's the point of `encodeURIComponent`. `@` becomes `%40`. Did you try it?

Comment: Whats up with that ugly `Base64` object? Looks irrelevant to this topic.

Comment: @Noitidart: actually in javascript there is function btoa() and atob() to encode string with base64, but not supported by lower versions of IE. So this Base64 is nothing but a function to encode and decode your credentials with Base64 conversion (in other words for cross browser)

Comment: @PriyankThakkar I don't see the relationship between my answer and your edit. Unless there is one and I'm missing it, you should create a new answer rather than editing this one. 

Also, where is the Base64 object used and where is `encodedCredentials` defined?

Comment: @PriyankThakkar I agree with other comments, this question is strictly related to the Add-on SDK and does not require cross-browser shims.

Comment: @canuckistani: Well answer is very simple. I buidling same addon not only for firefox but also for ie and chrome. I am reusing the logic. Why should i restrict my self to firefox only?

Comment: Regardless - my last edit answers the question as stated and will help people using the SDK in the future.